# Is there a way to generate a query string with both inlined and indexed parameters?

Tags: jooq

On the `org.jooq.Query.getSQL(ParamType paramType)`method

Like `ParamType.NAMED_OR_INLINED`, but printing `?` instead of the named parameter.

For example:

```
DSL.select(M3_PUSH.asterisk())
            .from(M3_PUSH)
            .where(M3_PUSH.PLATFORM.eq(param(String.class)).and(M3_PUSH.ALERTKEY.eq("TEST")))
            .getSQL()
```

Generates:

```
select "m3_push".* from "m3_push" where ("m3_push"."platform" = ? and "m3_push"."alertKey" = ?)
```

Whereas I'd like to have the second bindable parameter to be fixed:

```
select "m3_push".* from "m3_push" where ("m3_push"."platform" = ? and "m3_push"."alertKey" = "TEST")
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of some query output that you want to achieve?

Comment: @LukasEder Sure, added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexed or inlined parameters can be controlled on several levels. The first two don't work for you because they act globally:

- Globally for all queries e.g. using [`Settings.paramType`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#paramType)
- Globally for a single query using [`Query.getSQL(ParamType)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL-org.jooq.conf.ParamType-), which you tried
- Locally on a per-value level, using [`DSL.inline()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline-T-). This is what you need

See also:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters

Comment: It seems it is not possible to globally default to INLINE and to locally use indexed parameters, right?

Comment: @ftkg: No. When would that be a desireable *general* use case?

Comment: I have some larger queries with many fixed rules and few parameters, so it'd be easier to default to inline and use `param()` whenever it shows up. Otherwise I'll have to change the `paramType` and use a lot of `DSL.inline()`, and that seems a bit error-prone.

Comment: @ftkg: I see. Well, that's really the exception here. The rule is that people want bind variables, and rarely inline values. But you know what, here's what we could do in a future version of jOOQ. `DSL.val()` always produces a bind variable, and `DSL.inline()` always produces an inline value, but the default of producing bind values when writing e.g. `FIELD.eq(1)` could be overridden using a `Setting`. It would be a bit of effort, internally, but manageable. I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8687

Comment: As a hack, you could, of course, implement a `VisitListener` that visits every `org.jooq.Param` and replaces it by its inverse, reversing its `ParamType`. That way, you would get inline values by default, and if you wanted to get a bind variable, you could use `inline()`. A hack, as I said :)